# how to make a relation in laravel in model?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, relationship

i have 2 tables in db

`1) Orders`       its model is Order

`2) Ordertakers` its model is Ordertaker

**every order is created by order taker i want to count number of orders by `ot_id` somewhat like this condition**

```
Order::where('ot_customer_distance', '<' , 50)->where('ot_id', $id)->get();
```

so in model i used this

```
class Ordertaker extends Model
{   
    public function vistorders(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order','ot_id')->where('ot_customer_distance', '<' , 50)->count();
    }
}
```

my controller is

```
public function index()
    {
        $ids = [Auth::id()];
        if (Auth::user()->role < 3) {
            $ids = array_merge($ids, User::where('ot_of', Auth::id())->pluck('id')->toArray());
        }
        $ordertaker = User::where('role', 5)->has('ordertaker')->with('ordertaker');
        $ordertaker = $ordertaker->where('ot_of', Auth::id());
        $ordertaker = $ordertaker->get();
        return view('all_ordertakers', compact('ordertaker'));
     
    }
```

and my blade is

```
@foreach($ordertaker as $ot)
<td><b>Total Vst</b><br>{{ sizeof($ot->vistorders) }}</td>
@endforeach
```

but my result is 0 any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the number of orders by ot_id, then the relationship must be defined differently. An `OrderTaker` hasMany `Order`s, it does not belong to an order. Also, the where and count query should not be defined in the relationship.

```
public function vistorders(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order','ot_id');
}
```

Now referencing `$ot->vistorders` will return the eloquent collection of the order takers `Order`s. So you can use `$ot->vistorders->count()` to get the full count. Calling `$ot->vistorders()` will return the query builder which you can then call `$ot->vistorders()->where('ot_customer_distance', '<' , 50)->count()` if you need that value.

Also, you are eager loading the `ordertaker` relationship here:

```
$ordertaker = User::where('role', 5)->has('ordertaker')->with('ordertaker');
```

You can go one step further by using dot syntax to eager load the `visitorders` as well:

```
$ordertaker = User::where('role', 5)->has('ordertaker')->with('ordertaker.visitorders');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code.

1. You are using Eager/Lazy Loading but calling the class name instead of relation/function name. Correct this first.
2. The where conditions can't be performed on the relation.